# Google App Engine - Does the non-main version of an App not receive as many resources?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm doing performance tests on my app engine app.  I'm doing it on the non main version of my app.  Do loading requests take longer for the non main version of an app?

Comment: Is it possible that your main version is hit often enough that it is constantly in memory, whereas your non main version is hit less often, so it is starting a new instance every time you hit it?

Comment: @Peter My main version is hit more often, but i do distinguish in my logs between loading requests and regular requests. Loading requests for my main version seem to take less time, but maybe its just my imagination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they don't.

Comment: So I should only do performance testing on the main version of my app if I want accurate results for how long certain operations will take?

Comment: Sorry, thought you meant "No, they don't receive as many resources."  Guess you could have also meant "No, they don't take longer for loading requests."

Comment: Yes, I meant the latter - they don't take longer for loading requests. You might see more loading requests, though, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't noticed any performance difference between versions.  The logs don't show any significant differences.  I use this for staging new versions before making it the default.  I haven't seen an official answer